# not getting the appropriate output from the while loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I have made a program to find the leap years in the range given by the user, but I am not getting the correct output. Can someone please help my get the correct output.
my code:

```
#program to find leap years in the range given by the user
first_no = input("enter the starting year: ")
last_no = input("enter the end year: ")

for i in range(int(first_no), int(last_no)):
    while i % 4 == 0:
        print (i)
        i += 1
    while (i % 4 == 1 or i % 4 == 2 or i % 4 == 3):
        print (i)
        i = int(i) + 1
```

I am getting this output:

```
enter the starting year: 2000
enter the end year: 2021
2000
2001
2002
2003
2001
2002
2003
2002
2003
2003
2004
2005
2006
2007
2005
2006
2007
2006
2007
2007
2008
2009
2010
2011
2009
2010
2011
2010
2011
2011
2012
2013
2014
2015
2013
2014
2015
2014
2015
2015
2016
2017
2018
2019
2017
2018
2019
2018
2019
2019
2020
2021
2022
2023
```

The desired out is:

```
enter the starting year: 2000
enter the end year: 2021
2000
2004
2008
2012
2016
2020
2001
2002
2003
2005
2006
2007
2009
2010
2011
2013
2014
2015
2017
2018
2019
```

kindly tell me where is the mistake and how can I solve it. also please tell me why was I getting this output.

Comment: Please write in the question that you want to print the leap years first, in order, then the remaining years, in order.  In other words, you want to sort the years so that the leap years come first, and then print them, one in a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to find leap year simply checking if the year can be divided by 0, then print in the console. And if you using variable I in for-loop, you don't need to increment it manualy.

```
#program to find leap years in the range given by the user
first_no = input("enter the starting year: ")
last_no = input("enter the end year: ")

year1 = []
year2 = []

for i in range(int(first_no), int(last_no)):
    if i % 4 == 0:
        year1.append(i)
    else:
        year2.append(i)
        
year1.extend(year2)
print(year1)
```

Comment: I know that, but I also want to print the years which are left out(like 2001, 2002 and 2003), and this code will only print the leap years.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to create two lists and use one `for` loop with an `if` statement to get the leap years `if year % 4 == 0` and the remaining years otherwise. E.g.:

```py
first_no = input("enter the starting year: ")
last_no = input("enter the end year: ")

leap_years = []
remaining_years = []

for year in range(first_no, last_no):
    if year % 4 == 0:
        leap_years.append(year)
        continue
    remaining_years.append(year)

[print(year) for year in leap_years]
[print(year) for year in remaining_years]
```

Comment: I know that, but I also want to print the years which are left out(like 2001, 2002 and 2003), and this code will only print the leap years.

Comment: @HoneyKhandelwal, ok, so you will need two lists in this case. Instead of the list comprehension, a more clear way is a standard `for` loop with `if` statement. l updated my answer.